# Pie chart with non labelled data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I produce a pie chart when the data is not labelled as usual? See the example  dataframe below:

```
             First_Half Second_Half
Div
Bundesliga      0.438       0.562 
EPL             0.434       0.566
La Liga         0.441       0.559
```

This just shows the proportion of first half goals vs second half goals for the divisions listed. I want to create a separate pie chart for each division with the proportion of First Half vs Second Half goals, how do I do this with this data?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({"Bundesliga":[0.438, 0.562],
                  "EPL": [0.434, 0.566],
                  "La Liga": [0.441, 0.559]}, index=["1st_Half", "2nd_Half"])

df.plot.pie(subplots=True, , figsize=(10, 5), legend=False,
            title="Goals Ratio between first and second halves")
plt.show()
```

which will produce this graph:
[image]

Comment: With OP's original dataframe, you could transpose it:  `df.T.plot(kind='pie', subplots=True, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Given your dataframe, you can also do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = # your data

for i in range(len(df)):
    df.iloc[i].plot.pie()
    plt.show()
```